# VScrollbar is not visible untill it is clicked

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

What should be added in order to the vertical scrollbar to be visible without to be clicked or touched ? Here is image of screen :

[image]

Here is code :

```
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" paddingTop="5" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
            <s:TextInput id="chp1" width="50%"/>
            <s:TextInput id="chp2" width="50%"/>
            <s:Button label="Enregistrer" click="enregistrer(event)" styleName="btn"/>
            <s:Label/>
            <s:Button label="Lire" click="lire(event)" styleName="btn" />
            <s:TextArea id="area"/>
            <s:Label/>
            <s:HGroup> 
                <s:Button label="Envoyer" click="send(event)" styleName="btn" />
                <s:Button label="Retour" click="navigator.popView()" styleName="btn" />
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:TextArea id="resultHTTP"/>
            <s:TextInput id="h_url" text="{url}" visible="false"/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
```

As you see the vertical scrollbar at the right of the screen is not visible. So how to make it visible anytime ?

Comment: I asked the same question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176918/always-display-a-scroll-bar-in-a-mobile-spark-components-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, on your scroller:

> verticalScrollPolicy = "on"

---

**Update:**

What about trying this:

```
interactionMode="mouse"
```

;)

Comment: Oops! Sorry... Your project was for mobile. The answer is updated